# regex to match max of input numeric string

Tags: regex

I have incoming input entries.
Like these

```
750
1500
1
100
25
55
```

And There is an lookup table like given below

```
25
7
5
75
```

So when I will receive my first entry, in this case its 750. So this will look up into lookup entry table will try to match with a string which having max match from left to right.

So for 750, max match case would be 75.

I was wondering, Is that possible if we could write a regex for this kind of scenario. Because if I choose using startsWith java function It can get me output of 7 as well.

As input entries will be coming from text file one by one and all lookup entries present in file different text file.

I'm using java language.

May I know how can I write a regex for this flavor..?

Comment: Where does this data exist?  In a database, in a text file, as variables in a Java program?  Can you define what a best match is?

Comment: Pseudo: `where starts with string, select where max length`

Comment: What language is this for?

Comment: Hi All, question updated..you can check now please...!!

Comment: Sort lookup table values in a descending order then iterate to match the very first number with `\b75?0?\b` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**This doesn't seem like a regex problem at first, but you could actually solve it with a regex, and the result would be pretty efficient.**

A regex for your example lookup table would be:

```
/^(75?|5|25)/
```

This will do what you want, and it will avoid the repeated searches of a naive "check every one" approach.

The regex would get complicated,though, as your lookup table grew.  Adding a couple of terms to your lookup table:

```
25
7
5
75
750
72
```

We now have:

```
/^(7(50?|2)?|5|25)/
```

This is obviously going to get complicated quickly.  The trick would be programmatically constructing the appropriate regex for arbitrary data--not a trivial problem, but not insurmountable either.

**That said, this would be an..umm...unusual thing to implement in production code.**

I would be hesitant to do so.

In most cases, I would simply do this:

1. Find all the strings that match.
2. Find the longest one.

Comment: Last 3 lines makes the answer. Rest is all complicated regex game.

Comment: @Rahul, I found it fun and rewarding to think through a regex solution, and I thought it may be useful for others as well. I made it clear, though, that it's not what I would recommend in a real-world application.

Comment: _The trick would be programmatically constructing the appropriate regex for arbitrary data--not a trivial problem, but not insurmountable either. That said, this would be an..umm...unusual thing to implement in production code._ I thought of the same. That's why I pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

`(?: 25 | 5 | 75? )`

There is free software that automatically makes full blown regex trie for you.
Just put the output regex into a text file and load it instead.

If your values don't change very much, this is a very fast way to do a lookup.
If it does change, generate another one.

Whats good about a full blown trie here, is that it never takes more than 8
steps to match.

The one I just did https://i.stack.imgur.com/txv8C.jpg
App [screenshot](http://regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)

Even a [175,000 Word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt) takes no more than 8 steps.

Internally the app initially makes a ternary tree from the input
then converts it into a full blown regex trie.